# How does EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString / SendAsync when event hub is down or connection string is wrong

Tags: .net, azure, azure-eventhub

I have a .net application writing to event hub via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient?view=azure-dotnet :

```
var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubName);
EventHubEvent e = new EventHubEvent() { ... }; 
eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(e))));
```

How does this code behave in case of : 
1. eventHubName is wrong
2. connectionString has wrong SharedAccessKeyName
3. Event hub is otherwise unavailable

the documentation is rather scarce and in my testing, it appears that nothing fails. CreateFromConnectionString returns a valid 'EventHubClient' object and SendAsync just returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 12/18: .NET framework**

If you're using .NET framework of event hubs as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-framework-getstarted-send#send-events), it still has the same error message as .NET core of event hubs in my previous answer.

In your posted code:

```
var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubName);
EventHubEvent e = new EventHubEvent() { ... }; 
eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(e))));
```

The reason you cannot see error message when use a **incorrect eventhub_name** or **incorrect SharedAccessKeyName** is that when you're using the **async** method `SendAsync`, you didn't specify async / await keyword.

If you want to see the error message when using `SendAsync` method, you should use the following code for testing purpose:

```
namespace Sender
{
    class Program
    {
        static string eventHubName = "your_eventhub_name";
        static string connectionString = "your_namespace_connection_string";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SendingRandomMessages();

            Console.WriteLine("**completed**");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async void SendingRandomMessages()
        {
            var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubName);
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var message = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+": ddd";
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, message);
                    //eventHubClient.Send(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
                    await eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} > Exception: {1}", DateTime.Now, exception.Message);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

when run this app:

1.Specify a wrong event hub name, you will receive an error: **The messaging entity 'sb://your_eventhub_namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your_eventhub_Name' could not be found.**  Screenshot as below:

[image]

2.Specify a wrong SharedAccessKeyName, you will receive an error:  **InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature.** Screenshot as below:

[image]

---

**12/17: .NET core**

The **method** / **dll(Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll)** in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient?view=azure-dotnet) you provided is a legacy one. You should use the new nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/) and it's related method for Azure event hub. For more details of sending / receiving event data, please refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send#send-events).

And if you follow the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send#send-events) to send events, then for your question:

> eventHubName is wrong

If eventHub name is wrong, when execute `SendAsync` method, you will receive an error: **Exception: Put token failed. status-code: 404, status-description: The messaging entity 'sb://your_eventhub_namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your_eventhub_Name' could not be found.**

The screenshot of this error:

[image]

> connectionString has wrong SharedAccessKeyName

If connectionString has wrong SharedAccessKeyName, when execute `SendAsync` method, you will receive an error: **Exception: Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature.**

The screenshot of this error:

[image]

> Event hub is otherwise unavailable

If Event hub is otherwise unavailable, for this case, I cannot make an event hub into unavailable status. But I'm sure it will return an error looks like **"the event hub is not found."** or **"the event hub is unavailable."**

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but this is for .net core applications. My app is an old .net framework app.

Comment: @GregBalajewicz, please see my updated section in the post, and let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, OK so when using async, it will effectively fail silently unless I await the task. Thanks for confirming